# Split relativelayout into two while having an object in the center

Tags: android, layout

What I want is two layouts with equal size in a layout and have an ImageView in the middle of the outer layout.

[image]

I did something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

             </LinearLayout>    


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ac_imageView_profile"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/ac_myprofileimg_progressbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#84B5FE"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

             </LinearLayout>    
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `fill_parent` is deprecated, you have to use `match_parent`. Then you have to do step by step.

You can use a `LinearLayout` to put your two colored rectangles. If you want them to have the same height, you just have to set the same value for the `android:layout_weight` property of the childs.

As you want to add an `ImageView` at the middle of this layout, you need to wrap the `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`.

Finally, you can now add your `ImageView` at the middle of the RelativeLayout by using the `android:layout_centerInParent` property.

The following example should give you what you expect:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="{first color}" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="{second color (yellow)}" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:width="wrap_content"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below structure :

```
<FrameLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout>
// both the relative layouts are here
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

allocate height dynamically

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float height  = outMetrics.heightPixels /getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    height/=2;
    imageView1.getLayoutParams().height=(int)height;
    imageView2.getLayoutParams().height=(int)height;
```

use  alignparenttop=true for one and alignparentbottom=true for second
and for the middle one. .  add center_horizontal=true and center_vertical=true